# How to echo If statement from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, if-statement, mysqli

I'm having troubles displaying the information in the IF STATEMENT inside of the while loop. Is it even possible to echo an if statement inside a while loop? please help!

This code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "databasename";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

$searchEscaped = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$searchEscaped' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "
    **if(!empty($row['image2'])) { 
    <a class='example-image-link' href='pictures/".$row['image2']."' data-lightbox='example-set'><img class='example-image'src='pictures/".$row['image2']."'  alt='Profile Pic'></a>
     }
      ";}
} else {
     echo "No users found";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to move your echo inside the if statement to only echo if the requirement is met:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "databasename";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

$searchEscaped = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$searchEscaped' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if (!empty($row['image2'])) {
            echo "
    <a class='example-image-link' href='pictures/" . $row['image2'] . "' data-lightbox='example-set'><img class='example-image'src='pictures/" . $row['image2'] . "'  alt='Profile Pic'></a>

      ";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No users found";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Here's an example of a function that would be usable throughout your script:

```
    function print_image($row_image){
        if(!empty($row_image)){
            return  "
        <a class='example-image-link' href='pictures/" . $row_image . "' data-lightbox='example-set'><img class='example-image'src='pictures/" . $row_image . "'  alt='Profile Pic'></a>

          ";
        }
else{
        return "";
    }
    }
```

you can call this function anywhere else in your script and do something like:

`echo print_image($row['image2']);`

or

`echo print_image($row['image3']);`

Comment: Thank you! I have other images that have this same if statement afterwards so I would like to echo out the entire statement.

Comment: @kenny I think the best solution in that case would be to create a function in order not to keep repeating your code.

Comment: @kenny I've made some additions that may help further.

Answer (score 3):

The if statement comes before the echo, if statement echo.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if( ! empty( $row['image2'] ) )
        { 
            echo '<a class="example-image-link" href="pictures/' . $row['image2'] . '" data-lightbox="example-set"><img class="example-image" src="pictures/' . $row['image2']. '"  alt="Profile Pic"></a>';
        }
    }
}
```